# XML - Help removing nodes being published

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

Any help much appreciated on this.

I'd like to remove certain nodes from being published in a feed from an external xml file, which I've styled with xslt.  Here is the feed:http://www.wcwg.info/feeds/localevents.aspx?a=00392&p=CM159EH&m=20.

The  nodes I would like to remove are:

> Local Events posted to WhereCanWeGo.com.00392CM15
>   9EH31/10/1007/11/1010001111111111111111111031
>   October
>   2010http://www.wherecanwego.com/events/signin.aspxww.wherecanwego.com/events/signin.aspx

Could anybody be kind enough to direct me how to remove these initial nodes (parameters)?  They are the postcode, account number, feed URL etc.

I'm desperate to get this finished, but it's the final hurdle!  Many thanks in advance for anyone who responds...

The stylesheet (fragment)

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/>   
</xsl:template> 

 <xsl:template match="item"> 
  <div class="local_events"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>   
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Venue"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Times"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Dates"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DetailsURL"/> 
  </div><div style="height:1px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cfcfcf;"></div> 
 </xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="title"> 
  <h2><a class="title" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="{../DetailsURL}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a></h2> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Venue"> 
  <span>Location: </span> 
  <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
  <br /> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Times"> 
  <span>Details: </span> 
  <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
  <br /> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Dates"> 
  <span>Dates: </span> 
  <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="DetailsURL"> 
   <a style="font-weight:normal;margin-left:0.5em;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="{.}"><xsl:text>Full details...</xsl:text></a> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already use an XSLT stylesheet that does not do exactly what you want then please post the stylesheet or a link to it.
[edit]
In your posted stylesheet change

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//item"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, yes of course thanks for asking - I didn't want to bore anyone, so tried to keep it concise!  Here is my XSLT, and yep I'd love to know how to ensure the top child nodes (above 'item') aren't published:  I don't seem able to post he code here now!  I'll see how I can link to it...

Answer (score 0):

From your poorly formulated question and analyzing the feed, it seems that you want to get rid of all children of the top (`LocalEvents`) node that are not named `item`.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(self::item)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided feed (http://www.wcwg.info/feeds/localevents.aspx?a=00392&p=CM159EH&m=20), produces the wanted result**.

**Do note**: how the wanted elements are deleted (not processed, ignored) by an empty template matching them and overriding the *identity rule* that is used to copy the rest of the nodes "as-is".

Comment: Bit rude really, I don't think it was poorly executed at all.

Comment: @sue: even now, after @Alejandro put a lot of work to make it better, it lacks: 1. The source XML document; 2. Proper formatting that doesn't require horizontal scrolling. The XSLT code was not visible at all before the edit performed by Alejandro. Just in few words -- a typical example how *not* to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been corrected to the following which now works, for anyone else in the same situation:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/LocalEvents/item"/>    
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <div class="local_events">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Venue"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Times"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Dates"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DetailsURL"/>
  </div><div style="height:1px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cfcfcf;"></div>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <h2><a class="title" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="{../DetailsURL}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a></h2>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Venue">
  <span>Location: </span>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Times">
  <span>Details: </span>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Dates">
  <span>Dates: </span>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DetailsURL">
   <a style="font-weight:normal;margin-left:0.5em;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="{.}"><xsl:text>Full details...</xsl:text></a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other approuch. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="Times"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <div class="local_events">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
        <div style="height:1px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cfcfcf;"></div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <h2>
            <a class="title" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="{../DetailsURL}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </a>
        </h2>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Venue">
        <span>Location: </span>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Times">
        <span>Details: </span>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Dates">
        <span>Dates: </span>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="DetailsURL">
        <a style="font-weight:normal;margin-left:0.5em;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="{.}">
            <xsl:text>Full details...</xsl:text>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: When doing a one to one transformation in the same hierarchy, it's enough to declare the rules for specific elements in input source and to overwrite the built-in rule for text node (output the string value) with an empty rule.